# Live binding property change for textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I have a `TextBox` control on my form that is bound to a property in my view model. The current behaviour works in a way that the view model will only get notified that the text in the `TextBox` was modified after the control loses focus.

How can I inform my view model whenever the `TextBox` changes state in real time? This is attached to a property in my view model that determines if the save button is enabled. So if I type one letter into this `TextBox` right away my save button should be enabled without having to lose focus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) on the binding to `PropertyChanged`.